# Building PCL file with CMake build system

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, point-cloud-library

I want to compile and run a c++ code using PCL. First I build the file by CMake build system 2.8.12. I choose the files and the folder to build then I choose Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 as compiler. Here are the errors I receive:

1)

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:423 (include):   include could not find
>   load file:
>
> ```
> Source/CMakeVersion.cmake
> ```

2)

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:435 (if):   if given arguments:
>
> ```
> "GREATER" "0"
> ```
>
> Unknown arguments specified

CMakeVersion.cmake is located in CMake folder in C drive where I have installed PCL and MS visual studio. Does anybody know why I receive these errors?

Comment: I expect the problem is a needed variable is not defined because CMake did not find one or more of the dependent packages and the CMakeLists.txt does not handle that.

Comment: @drescherjm the variable is defined in CMakeVersion.cmake file. First problem causes the second one. I mean it can't find CMakeVersion.cmake so it doesn't know the variable defined in that.

Comment: reinstall cmake and also install a cmake-gui / ccmake, it can show you that which files/headers it couldn't find. then you can check it more consciously.